# How to filter a column in list Python without pandas?

Tags: python, function

I have a list in Python. I need to filter a column without using Pandas. I tried as below. But, it doesn't work.

For example, I will do some calculations for just Country='Canada'.

```
filtered = [x for x in data if data[0] == "Canada"]
```

Comment: Could you tell us what your original list and your expected output looks like?

Comment: What does your data format actually look like? Is it a list? A dict of lists? List of lists?

Comment: Originally, I have a csv file. it holds data from 1960 to 2017 for countries. I need to calculate (for 'Sweden') the yearly percentage increase compared to previous year and the find the year that has highest increase in terms of percentage.
Columns like these: Country, 1960, 1961, 1962,... up to 2017.

Comment: So based on your edit, can you try something like `filtered = [x[1:] for x in data if x[0] == 'Sweden'][0]`

Comment: It gives "IndexError: string index out of range" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that your data is just an unbroken list. If you are right about every year from 1960-2017, plus the label column, there should be 59 entries per row.

I really suggest you first try reformat the data into list of lists or something similar, but try this in the meantime:

```py
# Reformat the data a little
data = [i for s in data for i in s.split('\n')]

# Filter the data
row_len = 59
filtered = list([zip(data[1:row_len], data[i+1:i+row_len]) for i in range(len(data)) if data[i] == 'Sweden'][0])
```

Edit: That *should* bundle the year with data for country (Sweden in this case).

Comment: Yes, right. I have 59 entries. I have tried your code. It gives below error. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Weird. Can you see what `len(data)` and `data[-1]` gives? I have a suspicion that your data is just the top row.

Comment: It gives these: len(data) -> 15371 and data[-1] -> '1079.608290526067\n'

Comment: Ok then I am not sure why it doesn't work. Does your data definitely have 'Sweden' in it? Maybe you could try make the condition a bit less strict, like `if 'Sweden' in data[i]`

Comment: In my data, I have a column as Country and Sweden it's a data under this column.  I need to filter it.

Comment: Does the code still give you the error if you remove the `[0]` at the end?

Comment: In this way, it doesnt give an error but it returns just []

Comment: Ok good that means that the data itself is not exactly 'Sweden'. Try use `if 'Sweden' in data[i]` or otherwise figure out why it doesn't match. Maybe it needs to be lowercase

Comment: When I look at the data, it looks like this in list format: '585.8500637823702\nAngola'             Angola is another country name. Maybe because of this, code cannot read country names.

Comment: Ah I see. Alright I will edit my solution to solve this

Comment: Right now, it gives values of filtered choice. I can use this code blog. Thank you so much.

Comment: Last question, can I bring column information next to these values?

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look at it and have a go at formatting the list you want yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try?

```
filtered = [x for x in data if x == "Canada"]
```

for nested data:

```
filtered = [x for x in data if x[0] == "Canada"]
```

Comment: or is data  nested list? can you post your data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the list?

From what you have provided, but I then it looks like you are missing a subscript.
try:
filtered = [x for x in data if data[0][0] == 'Canada']

This assumes that your column h headers are not part of your list. You can if they are then you are you would say that you data[1][0] rather than data[0][0]